# Read from serial port for set amount of time?

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I'm writing a C# program that reads numbers sent from an arduino to the serial port, puts them into a datatable and displays them in a chart. Currently when connect is clicked, it will continuously read in data from the serial port, by using a DataReceivedHandler event method.

I've got three buttons in the form:

- A 'runonce' button that will only capture a single data input
- A selectable time and 'timed' button that will allow data to be read for some period of time only
- A 'continuous' button that will allow data capture forever

When one of the buttons is clicked, the others are disabled and the clicked button is renamed to "Stop".

How would I enable this datareceivedhandler event to only trigger when desired as described above?

Comment: By setting some variables and checking their values in event handler of course.

Comment: What you *really* want is not add data to the table and chart.  Use a *bool* variable.  Tinkering with the event is only a good way to get data reception out of sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by adding and removing the serial port data received handler from within your button click events.
Your second case would probably want to remove the handler in response to a timer tick event.

Something like this:

```
    private bool serialPortCapturing;

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!serialPortCapturing)
        {
            serialPort.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort_DataReceived);
            serialPortCapturing = true;
        }
        else
        {
            serialPort.DataReceived -= new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort_DataReceived);
            serialPortCapturing = false;
        }
    }
```